# Elements not moving up after deleting other elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this piece of code

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('#deleteGoogle').click(function(){ $('#googleDiv').css('display', 'none'); });
     $('#deleteYoutube').click(function(){ $('#youtubeDiv').css('display', 'none'); });
     $('#deleteFacebook').click(function(){ $('#facebookDiv').css('display', 'none'); });
     $('#deleteTwitter').click(function(){ $('#twitterDiv').css('display', 'none'); });
     $('#deleteInstagram').click(function(){ $('#instaDiv').css('display', 'none'); });
     $('#deletePlus').click(function(){ $('#plusDiv').css('display', 'none'); });
     $('#deleteDrive').click(function(){ $('#driveDiv').css('display', 'none'); });
     $('#deleteLink').click(function(){ $('#linkDiv').css('display', 'none'); });
     $('#deleteGit').click(function(){ $('#gitDiv').css('display', 'none'); });
     $('#deleteSpace').click(function(){ $('#spaceDiv').css('display', 'none'); });
    });
```

```css
#bookmarkMenu {
     height: 350px;
     width: 250px;
     position: absolute;
     right: 40px;
     top: 53px;
     border-radius: 3px;
     border: 1px rgb(211, 211, 211) solid;
     background-color: rgb(240, 240, 240);
     overflow-y: scroll;
     overflow-x: hidden;
    }
    
    .logos {
     height: 40px;
     width: 40px;
     position: relative;
     left: 10px;
     top: 5px;
    }
    
    .bookmarkLinks {
     font-weight: 500;
     font-size: 20px;
     font-family: sans-serif;
     left: 50px;
     position: relative;
     bottom: 45px;
     width: 70px;
    
    }
    
    .logoIMG {
     height: 40px;
     width: 40px;
    }
    
    #lineBookmark {
     border: 1px rgb(211, 211, 211) solid;
     width: 249px;
     position: absolute;
     top: 1.4cm;
    }
    
    .delete {
     height: 30px;
     width: 30px;
     position: relative;
     left: 185px;
     bottom: 90px;
     cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    a {
     text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    a:hover {
     color: black;
    }
    
    a:visited {
     color: black;
    }
    
    a:link {
     color: black;
    }
    
    a:active {
     color: black;
    }
    
    .titles {
     font-weight: 500;
     font-size: 1.3em;
     font-family: sans-serif;
     text-align: center;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
     <title></title>
     <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    
   
    
    <div id="bookmarkMenu">
     <h1 class="titles" id="bookmarkWord">Bookmarks</h1>
     <div id="lineBookmark"></div>
    
     <a href="http://www.google.com"><div class="logos" id="googleDiv"><img src="googleLogo.png" title="Google" class="logoIMG"><h2 class="bookmarkLinks">Google</h2></a><img src="delete.png" class="delete" id="deleteGoogle"></div><br>
    
     <a href="http://www.youtube.com"><div class="logos" id="youtubeDiv"><img src="youtubeLogo.png" title="Youtube" class="logoIMG"><h2 class="bookmarkLinks">Youtube</h2></a><img src="delete.png" class="delete" id="deleteYoutube"></div><br>
    
     <a href="http://www.facebook.com"><div class="logos" id="facebookDiv"><img src="facebookLogo.png" title="Facebook" class="logoIMG"><h2 class="bookmarkLinks">Facebook</h2></a><img src="delete.png" class="delete" id="deleteFacebook"></div><br>
    
     <a href="http://www.twitter.com"><div class="logos" id="twitterDiv"><img src="twitterLogo.png" title="Twitter" class="logoIMG"><h2 class="bookmarkLinks">Twitter</h2></a><img src="delete.png" class="delete" id="deleteTwitter"></div><br>
    
     <a href="http://www.instagram.com"><div class="logos" id="instaDiv"><img src="instaLogo.png" title="Instagram" class="logoIMG"><h2 class="bookmarkLinks">Instagram</h2></a><img src="delete.png" class="delete" id="deleteInstagram"></div><br>
    
     <a href="http://plus.google.com"><div class="logos" id="plusDiv"><img src="g+Logo.png" title="Google+" class="logoIMG"><h2 class="bookmarkLinks">Google+</h2></a><img src="delete.png" class="delete" id="deletePlus"></div><br>
    
     <a href="http://drive.google.com"><div class="logos" id="driveDiv"><img src="driveLogo.png" title="Google Drive" class="logoIMG"><h2 class="bookmarkLinks">Drive</h2></a><img src="delete.png" class="delete" id="deleteDrive"></div><br>
    
     <a href="http://www.linkedin.com"><div class="logos" id="linkDiv"><img src="linkLogo.png" title="Linkedin" class="logoIMG"><h2 class="bookmarkLinks">Linkedin</h2></a><img src="delete.png" class="delete" id="deleteLink"></div><br>
    
     <a href="http://www.github.com"><div class="logos" id="gitDiv"><img src="githubLogo.png" title="Github" class="logoIMG"><h2 class="bookmarkLinks">Github</h2></a><img src="delete.png" class="delete" id="deleteGit"></div><br>
    
     <a href="http://www.myspace.com"><div class="logos" id="spaceDiv"><img src="myspaceLogo.png" title="Myspace" class="logoIMG"><h2 class="bookmarkLinks">Myspace</h2></a><img src="delete.png" class="delete" id="deleteSpace"></div><br>
    </div>
    
   
   
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

The problem is, whenever I want to delete a bookmark (by clicking on the image positioned on the right side of the bookmark menu), the element below the deleted bookmark only moves up a few pixels, and doesn't take its place. How can I fix that.

Comment: You have `<br>` between each item. You should set items spaces with CSS rather than using `<br>`'s

Comment: @ArturFilipiak thank u, I didnt notice that because i put them when i tried to make it position:absolute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply remove your `<br>` and than take to class "logos" `margin-top`. `<br>` it's not right way to make margin between elements!

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('#deleteGoogle').click(function(){ $('#googleDiv').css('display', 'none'); });
     $('#deleteYoutube').click(function(){ $('#youtubeDiv').css('display', 'none'); });
     $('#deleteFacebook').click(function(){ $('#facebookDiv').css('display', 'none'); });
     $('#deleteTwitter').click(function(){ $('#twitterDiv').css('display', 'none'); });
     $('#deleteInstagram').click(function(){ $('#instaDiv').css('display', 'none'); });
     $('#deletePlus').click(function(){ $('#plusDiv').css('display', 'none'); });
     $('#deleteDrive').click(function(){ $('#driveDiv').css('display', 'none'); });
     $('#deleteLink').click(function(){ $('#linkDiv').css('display', 'none'); });
     $('#deleteGit').click(function(){ $('#gitDiv').css('display', 'none'); });
     $('#deleteSpace').click(function(){ $('#spaceDiv').css('display', 'none'); });
    });
```

```css
#bookmarkMenu {
     height: 350px;
     width: 250px;
     position: absolute;
     right: 40px;
     top: 53px;
     border-radius: 3px;
     border: 1px rgb(211, 211, 211) solid;
     background-color: rgb(240, 240, 240);
     overflow-y: scroll;
     overflow-x: hidden;
    }
    
    .logos {
     height: 40px;
     width: 40px;
     position: relative;
     left: 10px;
     top: 5px;
        margin-top: 10px;
    }
    
    .bookmarkLinks {
     font-weight: 500;
     font-size: 20px;
     font-family: sans-serif;
     left: 50px;
     position: relative;
     bottom: 45px;
     width: 70px;
    
    }
    
    .logoIMG {
     height: 40px;
     width: 40px;
    }
    
    #lineBookmark {
     border: 1px rgb(211, 211, 211) solid;
     width: 249px;
     position: absolute;
     top: 1.4cm;
    }
    
    .delete {
     height: 30px;
     width: 30px;
     position: relative;
     left: 185px;
     bottom: 90px;
     cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    a {
     text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    a:hover {
     color: black;
    }
    
    a:visited {
     color: black;
    }
    
    a:link {
     color: black;
    }
    
    a:active {
     color: black;
    }
    
    .titles {
     font-weight: 500;
     font-size: 1.3em;
     font-family: sans-serif;
     text-align: center;
    }
```

```html
<div id="bookmarkMenu">
     <h1 class="titles" id="bookmarkWord">Bookmarks</h1>
     <div id="lineBookmark"></div>
    
     <a href="http://www.google.com"><div class="logos" id="googleDiv"><img src="googleLogo.png" title="Google" class="logoIMG"><h2 class="bookmarkLinks">Google</h2></a><img src="delete.png" class="delete" id="deleteGoogle"></div>
    
     <a href="http://www.youtube.com"><div class="logos" id="youtubeDiv"><img src="youtubeLogo.png" title="Youtube" class="logoIMG"><h2 class="bookmarkLinks">Youtube</h2></a><img src="delete.png" class="delete" id="deleteYoutube"></div>
    
     <a href="http://www.facebook.com"><div class="logos" id="facebookDiv"><img src="facebookLogo.png" title="Facebook" class="logoIMG"><h2 class="bookmarkLinks">Facebook</h2></a><img src="delete.png" class="delete" id="deleteFacebook"></div>
    
     <a href="http://www.twitter.com"><div class="logos" id="twitterDiv"><img src="twitterLogo.png" title="Twitter" class="logoIMG"><h2 class="bookmarkLinks">Twitter</h2></a><img src="delete.png" class="delete" id="deleteTwitter"></div>
    
     <a href="http://www.instagram.com"><div class="logos" id="instaDiv"><img src="instaLogo.png" title="Instagram" class="logoIMG"><h2 class="bookmarkLinks">Instagram</h2></a><img src="delete.png" class="delete" id="deleteInstagram"></div>
    
     <a href="http://plus.google.com"><div class="logos" id="plusDiv"><img src="g+Logo.png" title="Google+" class="logoIMG"><h2 class="bookmarkLinks">Google+</h2></a><img src="delete.png" class="delete" id="deletePlus"></div>
    
     <a href="http://drive.google.com"><div class="logos" id="driveDiv"><img src="driveLogo.png" title="Google Drive" class="logoIMG"><h2 class="bookmarkLinks">Drive</h2></a><img src="delete.png" class="delete" id="deleteDrive"></div>
    
     <a href="http://www.linkedin.com"><div class="logos" id="linkDiv"><img src="linkLogo.png" title="Linkedin" class="logoIMG"><h2 class="bookmarkLinks">Linkedin</h2></a><img src="delete.png" class="delete" id="deleteLink"></div>
    
     <a href="http://www.github.com"><div class="logos" id="gitDiv"><img src="githubLogo.png" title="Github" class="logoIMG"><h2 class="bookmarkLinks">Github</h2></a><img src="delete.png" class="delete" id="deleteGit"></div>
    
     <a href="http://www.myspace.com"><div class="logos" id="spaceDiv"><img src="myspaceLogo.png" title="Myspace" class="logoIMG"><h2 class="bookmarkLinks">Myspace</h2></a><img src="delete.png" class="delete" id="deleteSpace"></div>
    </div>
```